# Get the displacement component which is perpendicular to the triangle (finite element method)

Tags: calculus, geometry, numerical-methods

I have a triangle in the space(x, y, z). I know the displacements of three nodes in the vector form, namely

d1: 0.000131475, -0.000706995, 0.000754736

d2: 6.02E-05, -0.000662299, 0.000711364

d3: 0.000147876, -0.000661116, 0.000729507

Is there any way to know the displacement of the triangle in the normal direction
I searched online, and why the shape function is related to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Since the triangle is moving, and possibly deforming, I'm assuming that the normal direction that you are mentioning is with respect to the original configuration. Moreover, you need to know if you are moving "up" or "down" in the perpendicular direction... In practice, this triangle is probably part of a surface mesh and you need to know on which side of the mesh is your domain, normally one uses the exterior normal direction.

In any case, from the initial coordinates of vertices you can compute the normal direction. If the vertices are $\vec v_1$, $\vec v_2$ and $\vec v_3$, a unit normal vector can be given by
$$
\vec{n} = \dfrac{(\vec v_2- \vec v_1)\times (\vec v_3 - \vec v_1)}{\|(\vec v_2- \vec v_1)\times (\vec v_3 - \vec v_1)\|}
$$

Depending on additional information that you are not providing, you may need to change the sign. Having $\vec n$, you can now project each displacement on this direction.

Please note that if the triangle is indeed part of a surface mesh, this is not a consistent way of defining the outward normal as it would be discontinuous across elements.